# which library is needed for including sdl/sdl.h

Tags: c++, sdl

which libraries do i have to download to include SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h and SDL/SDL.h
in linux ubuntu

Answer (score 8):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) and [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/) are the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.libsdl.org/